# View box model for all elements on a page simultaneously?

Tags: html, css, box

I'm teaching someone about HTML/CSS & the box model, and have been using the dev tools>layout to show the individual box model for a specific element.

My student was asking if there was a way to enable *ALL* box models of all elements at the same time.

Is there any way to achieve this?

TIA!

Comment: Yes and no, please include your code.

Comment: Hi @MrT - I just mean on any page (like this one).

Comment: @MrT Yep! Thank you!